# How to prove a statement with quantifiers is a tautology

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have a few questions regarding quantified predicates and I'm struggling to understand, pleasure bare with me.

[image]

I'm looking for whether two statements are equivalent (I must test both directions) and both must be true in order for it to be equivalent.  For statement #1 it is a tautology, and I have a proof of why it works. Here comes my issue, if I use the same Ideas for my proof of statement #1 to solve for statement #2 I get that statement #2 is also true, which is incorrect as I can find multiple counterexamples to statement #2.

Hence

option 1) my proof for statement 1 is flawed.
option 2) When applying the same rules for proof 1 to proof 2, I am breaking a rule and not noticing
option 3) I do not understand what I'm doing

Here is my proof for statement 1

[image]

Here is my "proof" for statement 2
[image]

To summarize, is my proof for statement 1 valid? if so why is also working for statement 2? where is my issue? Thank you for your time, and sorry pictures, I do not remember how to code at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof of statement 1 is correct.  The mistake in your proof of statement 2 is the step $\{x \mid P(x, d_0)\} = U$.  Here's why it's wrong:  You started with an arbitrary $c \in U$, and you showed that you could choose a $d_0$ such that $P(c, d_0)$ is true.  But the choice of $d_0$ might depend on $c$; for different choices of $c$, the choice of $d_0$ might be different.  So you can't say that, for the $d_0$ you selected, $\{x \mid P(x, d_0)\} = U$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. Also if by any chance you are Daniel J. Velleman author of "how to prove it", I'm reading your book.

Comment: Yes, that's me.

Comment: Thats amazing! such a pleasure. If its not much of a bother. May I also ask, is using the meaning of universal and existential quantifier the only way to prove that predicates with quantifiers are equivalent? I know I can disprove some by giving p(x,y) a meaning but if I wanted to prove them, is this the only way?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question means.  There are rules you can sometimes use to work out equivalences, such as $\neg \forall x P(x)$ is equivalent to $\exists x \neg P(x)$ or $\forall x(P(x) \wedge Q(x))$ is equivalent to $\forall x P(x) \wedge \forall x Q(x)$.  But there is no mechanical procedure for testing equivalence (in contrast to propositional logic, where truth tables give you a mechanical procedure for testing equivalence).  So in general, you have to reason in both directions to establish an equivalence.

Comment: I see. I was looking for a mechanical procedure to test equivalences. I thought if I just wrote out what each expression meant (what I did in the exercises above) I would always be able to tell if an equivalence is true or not. Then again, I would still have to reason.